# Django: efficient semi-random order_by for user-friendly results?

Tags: django, django-models

I have a Django search app with a Postgres back-end that is populated with cars. My scripts load on a brand-by-brand basis: let's say a typical mix is 50 Chryslers, 100 Chevys, and 1500 Fords, loaded in that order.

The default ordering is by creation date:

```
class Car(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=500)
  brand = models.ForeignKey(Brand, null=True, blank=True)
  transmission = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=TRANSMISSIONS) 
  created = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
  class Meta:
      ordering = ['-created']
```

My problem is this: typically when the user does a search, say for a red automatic, and let's say that returns 10% of all cars:

```
results = Cars.objects.filter(transmission="automatic", color="red")
```

the user typically gets hundreds of Fords first before any other brand (because the results are ordered by `date_added`) which is not a good experience.

I'd like to make sure the brands are as evenly distributed as possible among the early results, without big "runs" of one brand. Any clever suggestions for how to achieve this?

The only idea I have is to [use the ? operator with `order_by`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#order-by):

```
results = Cars.objects.filter(transmission="automatic", color="red").order_by("?")
```

This isn't ideal. It's expensive. And it doesn't *guarantee* a good mix of results, if some brands are much more common than others - so here where Chrysler and Chevy are in the minority, the user is still likely to see lots of Fords first. Ideally I'd show all the Chryslers and Chevys in the first 50 results, nicely mixed in with Fords.

Any ideas on how to achieve a user-friendly ordering? I'm stuck.

Comment: How about ordering by `('name', 'brand')` ?

Comment: ...though not that different from random ordering really, in the sense that it doesn't put minority brands higher in the results listing - so the user is still likely to look at the first 20 results and think "all of these are Ford".

Comment: Well that was a very simple suggestion. One way you can do it is randomize the queryset results - `import random; x = [[i] for i in range(len(qs))]; random.shuffle(x)` - I m thinking of approaches without preprocessing

Comment: Or, if you want a consistent ordering, you can order the queryset by brand, and then reorder the elements by slicing it

Comment: This is where you start using Solr and then doing faceting and weighting results against each other. :)

Comment: @limelights thanks for the suggestion - I'd been wondering if that was the way to go...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing was adding a `priority` field on the model, and assigning a semi-random integer to it.

By semi-random, I mean random within a particular range: so 1-100 for Chevy and Chrysler, and 1-500 for Ford.

Then I used that field to `order_by`.

Comment: I was thinking about this today and came to the conclusion that a search should reveal all in order by name and that a tampered search result page is not expected behavior from a UX standpoint, IMO. Therefore I think you had it right from the get go.